# open window self and also execute javascript for the new window

Tags: javascript, html, window

after clicking a button, a new window is opened with:

the code i have in my javascript is something like that:

```
$("#kitchen_menu a").bind('click',function(e){
    if(window.location.href = "products.html")
    {
        make_kitchen();
    }
});
```

and it works just fine.

my problem is after this piece of code when im trying to execute some other code for this new page i just opened. i realized that the code below this line is executing before the page is loaded.

how can i load my new page and execute some other functions for the new page? is there anything that can make the rest of the code wait until the page is loaded?

Comment: can you put the javascript inside the new page that you're loading?

Comment: window.location.href will just navigate to the specified url in the existing window (self) - are you opening a NEW window or navigating away from the page?

Comment: im currently navigating in "index.html", and when i click a button im executing the above code.

"products.html" has already some functions to execute 'onLoad' and those functions are in the same javascript file im doing the above code. is it possible that it waits to execute all the code and then load 'products.html'?

Comment: i put my code that i have in the javascript in the first question above.

Comment: maybe you could check out the .call method to change the scope of the reference

Answer (score -1):

use the jquery function document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // enter the code that needs to bee xecuted after the page is loaded
})
```